# Prove that $(\|x\|^p_X + \|y\|^p_Y)^{1/p}$ is a norm

Tags: analysis, normed-spaces

Let $X$ and $Y$ be normed spaces equipped with the norms $\|\cdot\|_X$ and $\|\cdot\|_Y$, then prove that the following defines a norm on $X\times Y$ for $1\le p < \infty$:

$\|(x,y)\| := (\|x\|^p_X + \|y\|^p_Y)^{\frac{1}{p}}$

The only awkward part of this proof is proving the triangle inequality. I have tried using the convexity of $f(x) = x^p$ to no real avail and beyond that I am pretty stuck for ideas.

Comment: Hint: Do you know the $L^p$-norm on $\mathbb R^n$? This norm is defined by $\|(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\|_p = (|x_1|^p + \cdots + |x_n|^p)^{1/p}.$ The construction in your question simply uses this norm on $\mathbb R^2.$

Answer (score 3):

$$ \| (x_1,y_1)+(x_2,y_2)\|=\|(x_1+x_2,y_1+y_2)\| =(\| x_1+x_2\|_{X}^{p}+\| y_1+y_2\|_{Y}^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq$$
$$ \leq ((\| x_1\|_X+\|x_2\|_{X})^{p}+(\| y_1\|_Y+\|y_2\|_{Y})^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}\leq$$
(we use [Minkowski inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality))
$$\leq (\| x_1\|_{X}^{p}+\|y_1\|_{Y})^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}+(\| x_2\|_{X}^{p}+\|y_2\|_{Y})^{p})^{\frac{1}{p}}=\|(x_1,y_1)\|+\|(x_2,y_2)\|.$$